# changing specific names in list of lists in R

Tags: r, list

I've got a list of lists in R. I've created the following example list to illustrate my problem:

```
example_list <- list(
                  list(id1 = 123, id2 = 321, school = 'notting'),
                  list(id3 = 12, house = 'Y'),
                  list(id4 = 18)
)
```

What I want to do is basically replace the name of the id elements to one consistent name, i.e. id. so my output would be:

```
 solution_list <- list(
                  list(id = 123, id = 321, school = 'notting'),
                  list(id = 12, house = 'Y'),
                  list(id = 18)
)
```

Note that a sub list may contain multiple id_ elements.

I've written this function to act on each sublist:

```
replace_names<- function(x, r) {
indices <- grepl(r, names(x))
if(length(indices) > 0) {names(x)[indices] <- r}
```

}

my idea was to use:

```
lapply(example, replace_names, r = "id")
```

though my function isn't working for some reason, and the approach seems a bit hacky, any suggestions?

Comment: We have 2 same names inside our list? `list(id = 123, id = 321...`

Comment: @zx8754 yes, perhaps this is a poor example, my actual data set has multiple id's with the same value in the same list `list(id1 = 123, id2 = 123)` etc

Comment: Understood, how are you going to address the second `id` in the list by name?

Comment: @zx8754 after this step, i've deleted duplicates

Comment: If you want to delete duplicates it doesn't seem necessary to change the list names.

Comment: @Roland the main purpose of this is to get the id field in multiple lists having the same 'id' title, the duplicates issue is not major -- the main point of this is to have those ids in the same column in a dataframe

Comment: Could you add expected final data frame to your post?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We replace the `names` of the `list` elements that have 'id' followed by numbers (using `grep`) to 'id', and return the `list` element.

```
sol_list <- lapply(example_list, function(x) {
                   names(x)[grep("id", names(x))] <- "id"
                    x})
identical(solution_list, sol_list)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or another option is using `sub` to remove the numbers from the `names` (as there is only 'id' with numbers as suffix

```
lapply(example_list, function(x) setNames(x, sub("\\d+", "", names(x))))
```